# Problem at tweeting with ESP8266 via Thingspeak

Tags: twitter, arduino, esp8266

I programmed my ESP8266 to read the soil moisture. Depending on the moisture a water pump gets activated. Now I wanted the ESP to tweet different sentences, depending on the situation.
Therefore I connected my twitter account to thingspeak.com and followed this [code](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=3120)
Connecting to the internet works fine.

Problems:
It does not tweet every time and if it tweets, only the first word from a sentence shows up at twitter.

According to the forum, where I found the code, I already tried to replace all the spaces between the words with "%20". However then nothing shows up at twitter at all. Also single words are not always posted to twitter.

This is the code I have problems with:

```
// if connection to thingspeak.com is successful, send your tweet!
if (client.connect("184.106.153.149", 80))
{
  client.print("GET /apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update?key=" + API + "&status=" + tweet + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\r\n");
    client.print("Accept: */*\r\n");
    client.print("User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua; Windows NT 5.1)\r\n");
    client.print("\r\n");
  Serial.println("tweeted " + tweet);
}
```

I don't get any error messages.
Maybe you could help me to make it visible if the tweet was really sent and how I manage to tweet a whole sentence.
I am using the Arduino IDE version 1.8.9 and I am uploading to this [board](https://smile.amazon.de/gp/product/B074Q27ZBQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
The rest of the code works fine. The only problem is the tweeting.

#### Update

I now tried a few different things:

1. Checking server response

   Works and helps a lot. The results are:

   - Single words as String don't get any response at all
   - Same for Strings like "Test%20Tweet"
   - Strings with multiple words like "Test Tweet" get the following response and the first word of the String shows up as a tweet

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Server: nginx/1.7.5
>
> Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2019 18:44:22 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Length: 1
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Status: 200 OK
>
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, X-Requested-With
>
> Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
>
> ETag: W/"RANDOM_CHARS"
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
>
> X-Request-Id: THE_ID
>
> 1

I think the Content-Length might be the problem? 
But I don't know how to change it in this code.

2. Checking if the connection succeded

   I implemented this into my code an it never shows up on the monitor. So I think i never have a problem with not connecting.
3. Use a hostname instead of IP address

   I tried it and never got a bad request. On the other hand nothing shows up on twitter at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `tweet` variable contains any new-line characters (carriage return or line feed). For example, the following variable would cause problems

```cpp
String tweet = "Tweet no. 1\r\n";
```

due to the new-line characters at the end. These characters will cause the first line of the HTTP request to be cut short. I.e., instead of

> GET /apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update?key=api_key&status=Tweet no. 1 HTTP/1.1\r\n

it would become

> GET /apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update?key=api_key&status=Tweet no. 1\r\n

and the server would reject it with a 400 (Bad request) error.

On the other hand

```cpp
String tweet = "Tweet no. 1";
```

would be fine.

If your tweets may contain such characters, then try encoding them before passing them to `client.print()`:

```cpp
  tweet.replace("\r", "%0D");
  tweet.replace("\n", "%0A");
```

#### Use a hostname instead of IP address

According to https://uk.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/writedata.html, the relevant hostname for the API you are using is `api.thingspeak.com`. Use that instead of the IP address. This is preferable because the IP address a hostname points to can change regularly. (The IP address you are using doesn't even seem to be correct - and may already be out of date.)

I.e., change

```cpp
if (client.connect("184.106.153.149", 80)) {
```

to

```cpp
if (client.connect("api.thingspeak.com", 80)) {
```

#### API endpoint

Are you sure you are using the correct API endpoint? According to the link above, it looks like the API endpoint you need is https://api.thingspeak.com/update.json - so you may need to change

```cpp
client.print("GET /apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update?key=" + API + "&status=" + tweet + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
```

to

```cpp
client.print("GET /update.json?api_key=" + API + "&status=" + tweet + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
```

#### Check if the connection succeeded

Presently, your device sends the HTTP request if connects to the server successfully - but doesn't give any indication if the connection fails! So add an `else` block to handle that scenario and notify the user via the serial console.

```cpp
if (client.connect("api.thingspeak.com", 80)) {
  client.print("GET /apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update?key=" + API + "&status=" + tweet + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  // etc.
}
else {
  Serial.println("Connection to the server failed!");
}
```

#### Checking server response

To check the response from the server, add the following block to your main loop - which will print the server response via the serial console.

```cpp
delay(50);
while (client.available()) {
  String response_line = client.readString();
  Serial.println(response_line);
}
```

To clarify: that code should go inside your `loop()` function.

The response should include a status line - such as `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` if the request was successful, or `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` if there was a problem.

In the case of a `Bad request` response, the full message will quite likely contain more information about the precise reason the request failed.

#### HTTP vs HTTPs

Lastly, are you sure that the API supports (plain, unencrypted) HTTP as well as HTTPs? If not, that may be your problem.

Comment: Thank you, for your quick answer!

My `tweet` variable looks like this:

`String tweet = "Plants watered.";`
or
`String tweet = "Water level " + lvl + "."; //lvl is an int`

The problem is, that most of the time nothing shows up on twitter and if something shows up, it is only the first word (e.g. "Plants" instead of "Plants watered").
Replacing the space with "%20" does not help. In this case, nothing gets posted to twitter at all.

Comment: @MoLa: I have updated my answer with a suggestion for checking the server response and printing it via the server console.
I am not familiar with the ThingSpeak platform, but I suspect they have some sort of 'dashboard' - which would allow you to view the requests you have made with their API. If so, this may help you to view the reason for API failures?

Comment: Thank you for your tipps. I tried a few different things and updated the question.

Comment: @MoLa: I have updated my answer with a suggestion to double-check the API endpoint. If that doesn't work then I am out of ideas I'm afraid.